# Is it possible to put the captions generated by AI models back into the pdf file?

Tags: python, pdf, artificial-intelligence, text-files

I have a pdf that contains multiple pages where each page consists of texts and/or images. I have found ways to extract images from a pdf file and I have found ways to use AI models to generate captions for images. But is it possible to put back the captions generated by the AI model to the corresponding image in the pdf file? If it is possible, then what library should I use? Or does anyone know how to code it?

Comment: It sounds like you want to write some text above or below the image position on the page, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyMuPDF for writing text to PDF pages ... in multiple ways.

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

You need to locate the image position on the page first. Then decide about a rectangle (like above or below the image boundary box) to receive the caption text.

For example, assume the image boundary box is called `bbox`, then define `rect = (bbox.x0, bbox.y1, bbox.x1, bbox.y1 + 20)`. This is a rectangle below the image with the same width as bbox and a height of 20.

Then do `page.insert_htmlbox(rect, caption)` using the caption text.

That method also allows you to align (e.g. center) the caption text via HTML styling instructions, like `page.insert_htmlbox(rect, caption, css="* {text-align: center;}")`.

Comment: Thank you for giving suggestion. However, I am still confused on how to get the x0, y0, x1, and y1 values of each image present in a pdf file, since I have tried to use img_info[2] to get the bounding box values, however, what I got was only a single integer instead of a tuple of axes.

Comment: method `page.get_image_info` is a list of dictionaries, each representing an image on page. If there is only one, things are easy. Otherwise, you may become certain by looking at the bbox info in those dicts. When you extracted images for caption generation, you probably also were returned the image bbox on the page, or not? BTW the parameters of the method are "hashes" and "xrefs". They should be of no significance to you here. Best consult the documentation https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.get_image_info

Comment: What is the block number (int) on the .get_image_info ?

Comment: The appearance of any object on a PDF page is defined by some source code. The sequence number of any object defined in there is the block number. Larger number means "displayed after".